# How to increase lua execution timeout in haproxy?

Tags: lua, haproxy

I need to increase the lua execution time for haproxy. I went through the haproxy documentation but cannot figure out how to configure.

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html

- tune.idletimer
- tune.lua.forced-yield
- tune.lua.maxmem
- tune.lua.session-timeout
- tune.lua.task-timeout
- tune.lua.service-timeout

Above are the parameters that can help tune the time, but I don't know where and how to use these parameters. Can anyone help?

Comment: What are you doing that is timing out? it looks like the default timeout for a number of the settings is 4s, how long does it take for you to get the timeout error?

Comment: I am doing an api call. The script works fine if I run standalone but doesn't work with haproxy.

Comment: what is the runtime in the standalone environment for the script to complete?

Comment: real    0m3.407s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.000s